# OpenCV: How to use HOGDescriptor::detect method?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have succeeded in tracking moving objects in a video.
[image: http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/mw690/63a9e398jw1ecn39e3togj20jv0g1gnv.jpg]

However I want to decide if an object is person or not. I have tried the `HOGDescriptor` in OpenCV. HOGDescriptor have two methods for detecting people: `HOGDescriptor::detect`, and `HOGDescriptor::detectMultiScale`. OpenCV *"sources\samples\cpp\peopledetect.cpp"* demonstrates how to use `HOGDescriptor::detectMultiScale` , which search around the image at different scale and is very slow.

In my case, I have tracked the objects in a rectangle. I think using `HOGDescriptor::detect` to detect the inside of the rectangle will be much more quickly. But the OpenCV document only  have the `gpu::HOGDescriptor::detect` (I still can't guess how to use it) and missed `HOGDescriptor::detect`. I want to use `HOGDescriptor::detect`.

Could anyone provide me with some c++ code snippet demonstrating the usage of `HOGDescriptor::detect`?

thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you already have a list of objects, you can call the `HOGDescriptor::detect` method for all objects and check the output `foundLocations` array. If it is not empty the object was classified as a person. The only thing is that HOG works with `64x128` windows by default, so you need to rescale your objects:

```
std::vector<cv::Rect> movingObjects = ...;

cv::HOGDescriptor hog;
hog.setSVMDetector(cv::HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());
std::vector<cv::Point> foundLocations;
for (size_t i = 0; i < movingObjects.size(); ++i)
{
    cv::Mat roi = image(movingObjects[i]);
    cv::Mat window;
    cv::resize(roi, window, cv::Size(64, 128));
    hog.detect(window, foundLocations);
    if (!foundLocations.empty())
    {
        // movingObjects[i] is a person
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you don't cmake OpenCV with `CUDA` enabled, calling `gpu::HOGDescriptor::detect` will be equal to call `HOGDescriptor::detect`. No GPU is called.
- Also for code, you can use

  ```
  GpuMat img;
  vector<Point> found_locations;
  gpu::HOGDescriptor::detect(img, found_locations);
  if(!found_locations.empty())
  {
      // img contains/is a real person 
  }
  ```

---

**Edit:**

> However I want to decide if an object is person or not.

I don't think that you need this step. `HOGDescriptor::detect` itself is used to detect people, so you don't need to verify them as they are supposed to be people according to your setup. On the other hand, you can setup its threshold to control its detected quality.

Comment: The sample code you provided is about `HOGDescriptor::detectMultiScale`, and I need `HOGDescriptor::detect`.

Comment: BTW I use foreground/background segmentatiion to track the moving objects rather than `HOGDescriptor::detect`. So I need to decide if the moving object is a person or not.

Comment: @gouchaoer Then you need to do `HOGDescriptor::detectMultiScale` on these moving object.

Comment: In this scene, only 4 moving bojects are all persons. But in another scene, moving objects like cars may be tracked in rectangle. As you can see, the tracking window is perfectly. But `HOGDescriptor::detectMultiScale` try to check if there's a person at different location and different scale, which is slow. I need to detect if the whole rectangle is a person or not, detection only for once. So I need `HOGDescriptor::detect`

Comment: @gouchaoer I see. You can do similar by calling `HOGDescriptor::detect`, just like `HOGDescriptor::detectMultiScale`. Their input parameters are very similar except for less ones for the former.

Comment: @gouchaoer Updated. Hope it helps.