# opencv error assertion with roi

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to detect persons and other object using HOG classifier.I started by detecting persons by using this code:

```
    capt >> frame_capture;
    capt1 >> frame_capture1;
    cv::cvtColor(frame_capture1,gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(gray,contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
    vector <Rect> listOfRectangles;
    // detecting objects 
    listOfRectangles = drawBoundingBox(contours);

if(!frame_capture.empty()){
    for (int i =0; i<listOfRectangles.size();++i)
    {
        //rectangle (frame_capture, listOfRectangles[i],Scalar(255,255,0),1,8,0); //! display detections
        cv::Mat roi;
        roi.create(frame_capture.size(),CV_8UC3);
        cv::Mat image=imread("");   
         roi = image(listOfRectangles[i]);
            cv::Mat window;
            cv::resize(roi, window, cv::Size(64, 128));
            hog.detect(window, foundLocations);
            if (!foundLocations.empty())
            {
            cout << "person .." << endl;
            }   
    }

//oVideoWriter.write(frame_capture);
    imshow("video",frame_capture);
    waitKey(25);
}
```

I got this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat
```

I had used this link:[OpenCV: How to use HOGDescriptor::detect method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192984/opencv-how-to-use-hogdescriptordetect-method/36352130#36352130)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `imread()` you're passing an empty path, thus the image is not found and `cv::Mat image` has no data. In the next line you try to get a subimage (ROI) of an empty image and that's why you get the error.

You need to properly initialize your `cv::Mat image`. You can check that everything is ok by adding a simple validation after that line, such as

```
if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
{
    std::cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return;
}
```